# Triangular surface plot matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

I tried to plot this data in form of triangular data but I get this error:

```
ValueError: x and y must be equal-length 1-D arrays
```

Can someone help me on it?

Comment: If you want to plot data on a regular, rectangular grid, use `plot_surface`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. but for now, I'm searching for plotting it in a triangular grid

Comment: Why? The grid is already regular.

Comment: using the plot_surface I get this figure: https://matplotlib.org/_images/surface3d_demo1.png.                                     but I want it to look some way like that: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html#Surface-Triangulations

Comment: The example uses random numbers. In your case it would be `X = np.random.rand(1000)*10-5;
Y = np.random.rand(1000)*10-5;
Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2))`

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triangular surface plot X,Y,Z must be one dimensional array rather than two dimensional as in case of wireframe and surface plot.
Don't use np.meshgrid().